# UIScrollView inexplicably moving out of position

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, positioning

I have a UIScrollView added and positioned via Interface Builder, as part of a view controller on a navigation controller stack. When I push a new view controller onto the stack, then pop that new view controller, the UIScrollView in the original view has drifted upwards by exactly 52 pixels.

This ONLY happens on the device, and not the Simulator.

Any ideas what might be causing this? I can fix it retroactively with calls to re-position in the viewWillAppear/viewWillAppear, but for some reason on a very few occasions even this doesn't work, so I'd really like to fix the root cause. Thanks!

Note in response to comments: I'm hiding the navigation bar in the pushed view controller, but not the original view controller. Also note that there are several other UIView elements on the original view controller, but it's only the UIScrollView which is moving out of position.

Update: not hiding the navbar in the pushed view controller has no impact on the UIScrollView problem - but thanks for the suggestion, commenters.

Comment: Are you hiding the navigation bar?

Comment: Is the navigation controller toolbar on the view with the scroll view?  If not, the addition and then removal of that toolbar might be causing the shifting of the scroll view.

Comment: mkral/Conor - turns out you guys were right; I was hiding the navigation bar permanently on the original view controller, and this - why? - was causing the weird re-positioning in subsequent pushes/pops from the navigation controller stack. I fixed the issue by setting the autoresize mask on the UIScrollView to have a fixed upper strut. Since you both commented at the same time and sparked the solution, whichever of you puts your comment in an answer first, I'll mark as answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: if the navigation bar is being hidden on a view controller, and you don't want any subviews (which you added via Interface Builder) automatically re-positioning in unexpected ways, make sure the struts on the subviews are set to be fixed.